# How to call a specific cell selection based on user interaction in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview where the user taps on a couple of cells and depending on the tap, the image in that cell gets replaced by a highlighted image, to let the user know it has been selected.

One such cell is the USE CURRENT LOCATION cell.  Where the second cell just below that is an alternative SELECT YOUR CITY cell which calls a UIPicker.

What I want is that if the user taps on the USE CURRENT LOCATION cell (the image is replaced with a highlighted image) but if the user then taps on the SELECT YOUR CITY cell to bring up the picker, I need that the first cell image be set back to normal state.  This way Im telling the user, "USE CURRENT LOCATION" has been automatically disabled because you are selecting a city manually.

So I tried adding this line:

```
//Deselect Row 1
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:1 animated:YES];
```

inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath for case 2 (because case 0 is a cell with an image)

Comment: Sounds good. How did you try to achieve this?

Comment: Ok i just updated the code...

Answer (score 0):

In `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` set the `selectionStyle` to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` Or you do it in interface builder (The goal is to avoid blue/ or gray selection)

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SomeCellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    // Configure your cell

    return cell;
}
```

Then in `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` customize the behavior :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSIndexPath *useCurrentLocationCellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 
                                                                      inSection:0];
    NSIndexPath *pickCityCellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 
                                                            inSection:0];
    if ([indexPath compare:useCurrentLocationCellIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) {
        // The "use current location" cell was selected. Change the image to the highlighted image
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].imageView.image = highlightedImage;
    } else if ([indexPath compare:pickCityCellIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) {
        // The "pick city" cell was selected. Change the image to normal one. And show the picker using your code.
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:useCurrentLocationCellIndexPath].imageView.image = normalImage;
        //[self showCityPicker];
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is that my cells are static.  I dont have a cellForRowAtIndexPath (cFRAIP) method.  I do have a didSelectRowAtIndexPath (dSRAIP) method though.  So I would have to insert something to "tap" cell 1 when cell 2 is actually tapped in dSRAIP, but how?

Comment: Ok so for the selection you can set it in IB. What's your "use current location" cell row and section?

Comment: Im trying to understand your code. 1 section only.  cell 0 is a decorative image. cell 1 is UseCurrentLocation and cell 2 is PickCity.

Comment: I edited my answer. Tell me if you still don't understand something.

Comment: ok i understand you getting the index path. Im actually no longer using images, just changing the uilabel.textcolor simply because it looks better :)) but I can translate that part. what I dont understand is the if tests with NSOrderedSame.  But I want to actually FIRE OFF the tap in cell 1, so that everything in there also gets called.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSIndexPath/compare:

Comment: If you like you can use if(indexPath.row == 1) but in cases in which you have different sections that would not be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using:

```
//Deselect Row 1 - only highlights it
            NSIndexPath* selectedCellIndexPath= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
            [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedCellIndexPath animated:false scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
            [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:selectedCellIndexPath];
```